# How to add a popup to a polyline that will display whe hovering over a polyline on map for leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, polyline, r-leaflet

I have drawn out some polylines on my map and I am wondering if there is a way to display a popup marker for a polyline. Would there be a way where you could hover your cursor over a polyline and a popup would be displayed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnYg2.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Marc Rich, Welcome on SO. I guess you should find the answer to your question [here](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html)

Answer (score 2):

To add a popup visible only on hover use the `label` argument of your `leaflet::addPolylines()` call. You will want to point the `label` argument to a column in your data object (or an expression) using the tilde (~) notation.

You can use the `labelOptions` to finetune the appearance (I suggest direction top; noHide = T would keep the label always on).

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% # included with sf package
  st_transform(4326) # ... or an alarm will ring!

# a polyline, any polyline
ashe <- st_cast(shape[1, ], "MULTILINESTRING") # borders of county Ashe as a line

leaflet(data = ashe) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolylines(color = "red",
               label = ~paste("Here be county ", NAME), # note the tilde / ~
               labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F, direction = "top"))
```

[image: county ashe with a label on hover]